# Django: Remove form fileds based on some values in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

I want to remove some fields from a form based on some values in the database. I'm not using this form to insert the data into any database, I'm going to make a csv file from this form data. Also this form is **not related to any model.**

**forms.py**

```
class Registration_form(forms.Form):
    Applicant_Name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    Applicant_age = forms.IntegerField(label ='Age of Applicant')
    Applicant_email =forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
    Applicant_phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**views.py**

```
class Registration_View(FormView):
    template_name = 'EVENTAPP/Application.html'
    form_class = Registration_form
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        Applicant_Name = form.cleaned_data['Applicant_Name'],
        Applicant_age=form.cleaned_data['Applicant_age'],
        Applicant_email=form.cleaned_data['Applicant_email']
        Applicant_phone=form.cleaned_data['Applicant_phone']

       # do some operations if form data valid

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class es_event(models.Model):

    ev_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Event Name")
    ev_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date")
    ev_description = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name="Description")

    registrant_name = models.BooleanField(default=True )
    registrant_age = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registrant_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registrant_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registrant_institution = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    reg_open = True
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.ev_name)
        return super(es_event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('event_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^events/register(?P<id>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$', views.Registration_View.as_view(), name='event_application')
```

Now what I want to do is find a particular instance of **es_event** from the database by using the value of **"id"** in the URL.

Then if that instance has the attributes  **registrant_name,registrant_age**, etc is **True** then the fields **Applicant_Name, Applicant_age**, etc will be available on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX for that. I think [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) is an example similar to yours, just that instead of checking if the user exists, you check if your instance has desired attributes (registrant_name, registrant_age). And when you get JSON response you show/hide fields with Javascript.